# Improve performance for ListView of WebView list items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I'm using `ListView` with `WebView` list_item because we need perfect color and fonts. but its very bad on ui performance .
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `TextView` does not provide perfect color and fonts?

Comment: The view is dynamic sometimes it gives images, sometimes texts have different size and styles.